# Get reosurce in a modular project

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I'm working on a maven modular project that has a structure that look like at the following:

```
|-- parent
    |-- model
    --pom.xml
    |-- services
    --pom.xml
    |-- web-app
    --pom.xml
```

No in my service module I have some resources in src/main/resources. But when i try to get them:

```
String fileName = getClass().getResource("/myFile.txt").getPath();
map.put("myReport",JasperCompileManager.compileReport(fileName));
```

the file name has the following value

> file:/home/myUser/apache-tomcat-8.0.3/webapps/myApp/WEB-INF/lib/services-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/myFile.txt

and then when i try to use it i get :

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/home/myUser/apache-tomcat-8.0.3/webapps/myApp/WEB-INF/lib/services-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/myFile.txt
```

Also i saw others post (not resolved) like [Get file in the resources folder in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19115837/get-file-in-the-resources-folder-in-java) where somebody said the is not possible to get resource from different modules.

Is this true?
How can I do to fix it?

Comment: Looks like it's working fine, but you cannot use a `File` to access opaque paths. Post what you are trying to do. In the first instance I would point you to [`getResourceAsStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)).

Comment: your path has "!" in jar file name. Is it by mistake?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I Updated my question and there you can see that I'm trying to compile a report that i made with jasper report. I often used getResourceAsStream (and works fine) then I want to understand why getResorce("/myFile").getPath() try to acces at the .jar instead that at the classpath like getResourceAsStream does

Comment: Because, I'm assuming here, `JasperCompileManager.compileReport` takes a `File` path. What you have is not a file path, it's an _opaque_ path. The file is _inside_ an `.jar` and therefore cannot be opened like a normal file. The `ClassLoader` is specifically designed to load files from jars - i.e. classes. You can use the stream to create a copy _outside_ the jar and then this will work.